# "Se" and "le" with "usted", but always "te" with "tú"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

Why do we say

- te digo [a ti] / **le** digo [a usted]

but

- no te preocupes [tú] / no **se** preocupe [usted]

?

Aren't these equal in terms of grammar? If so, why with "tú" in both cases it's "te", but with "usted" it's "le" and "se"? How do I know when to use "se" and when "le" with "usted"?

Answer (score 10):

First, let's make a brief clarification: `usted`, in Spanish, is always **gramatically treated as a third person** (the same as `él`, `ella`, `ellos`, `ellas`).

Now, to your question. Indeed, `te`, `se`, and `le` are all personal pronouns. They're a special type of personal pronoun that we call **pronómbres personales átonos**. They can basically play two roles: as the **verb complement** (direct or indirect), or as the **reflexive particle** that you put before or after a verb.

Let's look at this useful table of pronómbres personales átonos:

[image]

As you may note, for the first, and second person pronouns (`yo`, `tú`, `nosotros`, `ustedes`), there are **only distinctions between singular and plural cases**. However, in the third person pronouns (`usted`, `él`, `ella`, `ellos`, `ellas`), **there are distinctions regarding number (sing. or plur.), gender (m. or f.), and syntactic  function (direct obj., indir. obj., or reflexive).**

In the first set of sentences that you put as an example, `le` and `te` are being used as the **indirect object**:

1. `A ti`: 2nd person singular = `te`
2. `A usted`: 3rd person singular as indirect object = `le`

In the second pair of examples, `le` and `se` are being used as reflexive particles of the verb `preocuparse`.

1. `Tú`: 2nd person singular = `te`
2. `Usted`: 3rd person as reflexive = `se`

Comment: Do you want to add a note to say why _os_ has an *? I assume it would say something like 'primarily in Spain' but I am not sure.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, you're right. I took the table from the DPD, and the asterisk in *os*  refers to the following explanation: "En América, en Canarias y en parte de Andalucía, no se usa el pronombre personal vosotros para la segunda persona del plural. En su lugar se emplea ustedes".